# Django queryset sum and average values

Tags: django

I have trouble in finding a sum and avg value of the shares bought, my code is as follows
models.py

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Name of Stock', max_length=300)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    purchase_price = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Purchase Day Price', blank=True, null=True, max_digits=30, decimal_places=2)
    pre_price = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Last Day Price', blank=True, null=True, max_digits=30, decimal_places=2)
    current_price = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Current Price', blank=True, null=True, max_digits=30, decimal_places=2)

class BuyStock(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock, verbose_name='Search')
    quantity = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Quantity Required',default=0)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
```

views.py

```
def stock_bought(request):
    queryset = BuyStock.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    context = {'queryset': queryset}
    return render(request, 'stock/stock_bought_list.html', context)
```

stock_bought_list.html

```
{% for item in queryset %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ item.get_absolute_url }}">{{ item.stock.name }}</a>
            </td>
            <td>
              {{ item.purchase_price }}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{ item.quantity }}
            </td>
        </tr>
   {% endfor %}
```

Now if the user purchase same stock many times the list also shows that much times separately, but I want it to be as a single item(based on name) and sum of quantity and average of price, hope somebody can help me, thank you.

Comment: Check annotate method: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add purchase price to the BuyStock model.

Then to get the average price:

```
queryset = (Stock
           .objects
           .filter(user=request.user)
           .exclude(buystock__quantity=0)
           .annotate(ave_price=Sum(F('buystock__quantity')*F(buystock__purchase_price'))/Sum(F('buystock__quantity'))))
```

This will add a property ave_price to each Stock instance.

I didn't test this but is should show the concept to you.

Also remove user from BuyStock

Comment: Owner is creating instances of stock, so he decide the purchase price, that is why I put in Stock model. What I wanted is, if buyer buys same stock many times, it should show as a single item with total quantity and average price. Now all purchase instances shows seperately.

Comment: @RodrigoEspinoza Added an exclude filter

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer above I concluded as follows.

```
qs =  BuyStock.objects.values('stock__name').filter(user=request.user).annotate(stock_name=Upper('stock__name')).distinct()
qs1 = BuyStock.objects.values('stock__name').filter(user=request.user).annotate(ave_price=Avg('stock__purchase_price'))
qs2 = BuyStock.objects.values('stock__name').filter(user=request.user).annotate(total_sum=Sum('quantity'))
```

an then combined it in template.